# Architectures for efficiently building Web Services?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, architecture

I was recently working on a Web Service Project and realized my choice of architecture was extremely inefficient.

I wrote this in a very procedural manner with a hint of OOP and standard Exception Handling using Python. Basically, it would procedurally step through the data, validate existence of expected data, validate the data against a regular expression, validate some data against a database, perform some specific logic, check for errors, and then finally return a response. It might be helpful to mention that all data was exchanged using JSON.

I tried to go back through the code, find any duplicated exceptions, and push their handling to the top of the logic chain. This was not as easy to do as I had hoped and actually cost more time. It also made my code more prone to bugs by being less Unit Testable and harder to read.

I've noticed this paradigm of procedural code for handling User Data is very easy to fall in to with Web Development. For example, while handling a Form in PHP one may run a consecutive series of isset() and !empty() methods on the data. My problem with this coding style is that I feel like I'm spending an enormous amount of time coding for Error Events and it's difficult to generalize and re-use code for this particular purpose.

Various frameworks offer great ways around this through the use of Form Classes (e.g. Django). However, I have noticed that while you save time by reducing the duplication of Validation Logic, you will still need to "build" a Form for each expected input. When dealing with Software as a Service, there can be potentially hundreds of API Methods that you must code for. OOP offers a benefit here but there are times where a client may set an odd requirement which removes any efficiency gained.

Web Applications can benefit greatly from following paradigms/architectures such as MVC. In my personal experience, MVC (and the frameworks which use its principles) are not well tailored to this type of problem. I've considered the use of Functional Languages but have yet to give them a try.

**Are there any particular languages, architectures/paradigms, conventions, or even example frameworks that are well suited for the development of custom SASS or Web Service Projects?**

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is really your "tricky part"? Is it the complexity and nature of user input? Is it the complexity and nature of your "business logic"? Do you have a plethora of edge cases that you cannot deal with?

Comment: hymloth, I believe my issue is with the complexity of the User Input and the plethora of edge cases. It's not that the task is impossible; but rather very inefficient development-wise. At one point, I had around 90% of my code simply dealing with edge cases while my actual logic was typically a few lines of code per "API Method". Many frameworks instill a convention upon developers which makes development faster and smoother but can drive you crazy when building extremely custom code. Short of writing a new framework, I've not come up with any solutions on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who does a lot of this work, I would say that part of your problem with OOP and PHP is caused because initially PHP was not an OOP language.  OOP was added to the language later on.  So when you look at code examples they often can have a procedural feel.

In recent years I've been most happy with either Spring (Java) or WCF (C#).  Both these languages are strongly typed OO languages.  From a conceptual standpoint this leads to a paradigm that works well for my projects.  Here's the overview:

1. Endpoints (Either REST or WSDL) -- similar to view in MVC
2. Services -- These feed the endpoints and coordinate DAOs as needed.  Organize these around your business logic
3. Data Access Objects -- convert data into native objects and vice versa.  Organize these around your data sources.
4. Model / API -- Native Objects to support application and automatically provide documentation for your service.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, Doorknob. I actually didn't use PHP on either of these projects but I can appreciate your comment on PHP and its non-OOP background. I'm typically a Python coder, these days.

I do agree that REST is very nice although was not an option in this project. I have never looked into WSDL, so I'll check that out. One difference I am noticing between my experience and your experience is that I'm not simply providing a layer of access to Data. In the points you mentioned, it appears you put data first. However, in the projects I've tackled, the emphasis is on the Methods, if that makes sense.

Comment: Regardless of my personal needs, I believe the Answer you gave will be helpful to others and provides some common conventions or architectures that are extremely useful. +1